# How is the prefix "uber-" differently used in German vs. English?

Tags: meaning, loanword, prefix, english

In English usage the prefix *"über"* (loaned from German) has the meaning of:

> **über-**, **uber-**: denoting an outstanding or supreme example of a particular kind of person or thing. <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uber-)</sup>

There is a similar meaning in German usage as well (e.g. *"Übergenau*", *"Überbevölkerung"*, *"überglücklich"*) but there are other words where *"über-"* seems to have another meaning:

> - *Überlegung/überlegen* = consideration/to consider
> - *Überweisung* = transfer
> - *Überraschung* = surprise
> - *Übersetzung* = translation

How is this usage in German different to the English usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is quite the nice article at the [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber) on the topic, also explaining the meaning of the term in German.

I was actually right with my guess that the English usage originates in Nietzsche's "Übermensch":

> The crossover of the term "über" from German into English goes back to
>   the work of German philosopher Friedrich Nietzsche. [...] The term was
>   brought into English by George Bernard Shaw in the title to his 1903
>   play Man and Superman. During his rise to power, Adolf Hitler
>   bastardized Nietzsche's term, using it in his descriptions of an Aryan
>   master race. It was in this context that American Jewish comic book
>   creator Jerry Siegel encountered the term and conceived the 1933 story
>   "The Reign of the Super-Man", in which "Superman" is "an evil
>   mastermind with advanced mental powers".[...] Throughout the following
>   decade, Siegel, and Joseph Shuster, recast Superman into the iconic
>   American hero he subsequently became. It is through this association
>   with Superman the hero that the term "über" carries much of its
>   English sense implying irresistibility or invincibility.

So there is a very big difference between the usage of those terms in English and German, they're really "false friends".

Answer (score 9):

"Über" has roughly the same meaning as the English word "over", but some uses are more metaphorical than others:

- Übertragung (transmission): literally translates to "carrying it
  over".
- Überlegung (thought): thinking it over.
- Überbevölkerung: overpopulation.
- Übergenau: overly precise.
- Überglücklich: overly happy.

For some reason, English speakers loaned the word only in its meaning of "overly/very much/too much", and not in the meaning of "across" or "about", but in German usage, there's not really a clear distinction.

Comment: I would actually say it comes from Nietzsche's term "Übermensch". It was actually meant as a being "above" the man ("über" also means "above", as in "das Bild hängt über dem Regal") in a more or less evolutionary way. However, it instead got the notion of a "super" kind of man - and a very sad counterpart in "Untermensch". For some reason the English world picked up the "super" notion and use it in this way till today.

Comment: @Ladybug: If you wrote that comment as an answer and elaborated a few bits I'd say it's a pretty acceptable answer.

Comment: Nietzsche's word *Übermensch* was also used by the Nazis in their rhetoric about the *Herrenrasse* (the master race). Further, the opposite term, Untermensch, was used in eugenics. So to the non-native speakers: be very careful when using it. It does have a very dark connotation outside of philosophical circles.